# On the output in the for loop it is displaying zero and not accepting the input I cannot figure out what i am doing wrong here

Tags: loops, for-loop, ostream, istream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;
class Inventory{
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Inventory);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Inventory);


private:
    int stock;
    int quant;
    int price;
public:
    Inventory(int=0,int=0,double=0);
};
Inventory::Inventory(int s, int q, double p){
    stock=s;
    quant=q;
    price=p;
}
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Inventory){
    int s;
    int q;
    double p;
    cout << "Enter stock number: ";
    in >> s;
    cout << "Enter quantity: ";
    in >> q;
    cout << "Enter price: ";
    in >>p;
    Inventory inv(s,q,p);

    return in;

}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Inventory inv){

    out << "The stock number is: " << inv.stock << endl << "The quantity is: " <<
    inv.quant << endl << "The price is: " << inv.price << endl;
    return out;
}
int main()
{
    Inventory inv[5]={};
    for(int i = 0; i <5; i++){
        cin >> inv[i];
    }
    cout<<"------------------------" << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        cout<<inv[i];
        cout<<"------------------------" << endl;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

I can not figure out why when I use the overloaded << operator in the for loop it is displaying zero's, am I not storing the price, quantity and price to the object array correctly? I have tried not using a contructor and using one it did not make a difference, any ideas why the integers and double are not storing to the array?

Answer (score 0):

Your were close!  See my **// change here** comment markers (there are several) in the code below.

The 0's had nothing to do with the << overload, but rather the >> overload.

The deal is that you can use the 'in' istream to input directly to the class variables (without trying to call some other function, or a need for extra variables) in the >> overload, but you need to pass an Inventory reference to do so.

I was surprised that there was no error trying to set primitives to 0 in the constructor parameters?? (I'm likely very 'rusty' on newer C++ handling, been over 15+ years for me), but anyway:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;
class Inventory{
    friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Inventory&); // change here (Inventory reference)
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Inventory);


private:
    int stock;
    int quant;
    double price;                     // change here
public:
    Inventory(int,int,double);        // change here
};
Inventory::Inventory(int s = 0, int q = 0, double p = 0){ // change here
    stock=s;
    quant=q;
    price=p;
}
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Inventory& inv){  // change here (inventory reference)
                                      // change here (removed variables)
    cout << "Enter stock number: ";
    in >> inv.stock;                  // change here
    cout << "Enter quantity: ";
    in >> inv.quant;                  // change here
    cout << "Enter price: ";
    in >> inv.price;                  // change here
                                      // change here (removed function call)

    return in;
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Inventory inv){

    out << "The stock number is: " << inv.stock << endl << "The quantity is: " <<
    inv.quant << endl << "The price is: " << inv.price << endl;
    return out;
}
int main()
{
    const int ITEMS = 5;              // change here (constant to replace hard-coded value)
    Inventory inv[ITEMS]={};          // change here (use the constant)
    for(int i = 0; i <ITEMS; i++){    // change here (use the constant)
        cin >> inv[i];
    }
    cout<<"------------------------" << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<ITEMS;i++){         // change here (use the constant)
        cout<<inv[i];
        cout<<"------------------------" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Give that a run and see how it goes:

Here's my example output when I changed the constant (my change inside the main function) to 2 for a basic test run:

```
Enter stock number: 123
Enter quantity: 4
Enter price: 2.1
Enter stock number: 467
Enter quantity: 1
Enter price: 1.2
------------------------
The stock number is: 123
The quantity is: 4
The price is: 2.1
------------------------
The stock number is: 467
The quantity is: 1
The price is: 1.2
------------------------
```